# PrimeNG data table sorting and pagination clicks is scrolling the page to top

Tags: angular, primeng

I am currently using PrimeNG Datatable with pagination enabled in it. When I try to sort any column or click on pagination butttons, the page scrolls to top.

It is because primeng anchor tags have href="#" by default, for example

```
<a class="ui-paginator-page ui-paginator-element ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" ng-reflect-klass="ui-paginator-page ui-paginator" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">2</a>
```

Is there a way I can override the href values to something else like href="#/" which would stop the scrolling to top? PrimeNG does not provide any configuration option for updating href tags.

Answer (score 0):

In your `node_modules/primeng/components/datatable/datatable.js` you can override the `href="#"`s. There's several different places that it pops up, so make sure you replace all the `href="\"#\"` with `href="\"#\\\"`. I'm not certain this will fix your issue, but this is where the links are located in your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the paginator.js inside the **node_modules/primeng/components/datatable/**

Line No:161 is the href what you are searching